# Media Queries with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, responsive-design, anime.js

Hey Everyone I want to know that can I use Media Queries with JavaScript and how especially with Animejs.

```
    var morphing = anime({
        targets: '.polymorph',
        points: [{
            value: '405,219 0,219 0,0 70,0 77.5,0 84,0 151.5,154.5'
        }, ],
        easing: 'easeOutQuad',
        duration: 1500,
        loop: false
    });

    anime({
        targets: '#blip',
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 7000,
        translateX: 290,
        loop: true
    })
```

I want to change duration and translateX when it is viewed in mobile device

```
        anime ({
        targets: '#blip',
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 7000,
        translateX: 290,
        loop: true
     })
```

Thanks

Comment: [CSS Media Queries - Examples](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp) and [How to Use Media Queries with JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_media_queries.asp)

Comment: How would you determine if device is mobile?

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Thanks Benvc I will check

Answer (score 0):

You can check the screen size of the window using `screen.width()` in your javascript code.

You can store the values of 'translateX' property of anime object in any variable. Then according to the screen size, you can set the values in that variable and ultimately assign the variable as the translateX property.

```
translateX: <your_variable>
```